# Set button made in js to route to another page in React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-router

Im making div element in *for-loop* and want to assign every div to link to */campaign* page with his *id*.

I want on div click to go to *"/campaign/id"* page and pass id to *Campaign* component.

```
class Home extends Component{
   ...
   async printCampaigns(){
        const totalSupply = 5
        const mainDiv = document.getElementById("myID")
            for(var i = 0;i<totalSupply;i++){
                const _div = document.createElement('div')
                _div.onclick = function() {
                    //I want this onclick to go to ("/campaign/" + _div.id)
                }
                mainDiv.appendChild(_div)
            }
    }
   ...
}
```

This is my Router code

```
const Routing = () => {
    return(
        <Router>
            <Header/>
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
                <Route path="/campaign/:id" component={Campaign} />
            </Switch>
        </Router>
    )
}

ReactDOM.render(<Routing />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

This class to open on /campaign/id and to have access to that id

```
class Campaign extends Component{
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use **setAttribute** function for set _div id and **window.location.href** for onClick event Like this :

```
  async printCampaigns(){
        const totalSupply = 5
        const mainDiv = document.getElementById("myID")
            for(var i = 0;i<totalSupply;i++){
                const _div = document.createElement('div');
                _div.setAttribute("id", i);
                _div.onclick = function() {
                    window.location.href="/campaign/"+ i;
                }
                mainDiv.appendChild(_div)
            }
    }
```

Comment: That works, thank you. I used `window.location.pathname.split("/").pop()` to get id in the other component.